# IBM BPM performance impact for interface systems

Tags: ibm-bpm

If there a performance impact of interface system service, how does it impact the overall BPM process? How can this be better handled in IBM BPM ?

Comment: Do you mean the "integration service" type?  If not, I am not sure what you mean by an "interface system service"?  Can you elaborate some more on your question?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am new to IBM BPM. Yes you are right, I mean how IBM BPM handles different complexities which may occur with implementation of different integration services.

Comment: This question is not specific enough.  There are a myriad of integration services with varying purposes and the impact will vary based on multiple factors including, the type of service, whether it's local or external, the skill of the developer... the list could go on.

Answer (score 1):

IBM BPM follow some  Best practices as discussed in Red Books . You can refer the below link :

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248216.html?Open (for Version 8.5)

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4935.html?Open (for Version 8)

Answer (score 0):

There're two integration types, one called Webservice integration (affect performance), second java integration doesn't impact performance but depend on best practices of java not bpm.

Comment: Thanks for response. What are the major area of performance impact and where can i get the best practices to be used for using webservices to improve the performances.

Comment: There's bookk called IBM BPM Performance guide V8.0 , V 8.5 , you can know more about best practices